# HighCharts errorbar not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently trying to display errorBars with a column chart which is working for the most part. The problem is the ordering of the error bars. They are back to font.

I have used the same data on a line chart which works fine for me.

This is my setup for my HighCharts options:

```
    "chart": {
        "type": "column",
        "renderTo": {}
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Line chart",
        "style": {
            "color": "#000",
            "fontFamily": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            "fontSize": "1.1rem",
            "fontWeight": "bold"
        }
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "Browser market share data 2019-2020",
        "style": {
            "color": "#000",
            "fontFamily": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            "fontSize": "0.9rem",
            "fontWeight": "regular"
        }
    },
    "xAxis": [
        {
            "categories": [
                "Chrome",
                "Internet Explorer\n                  ",
                "Firefox\n                  ",
                "Edge\n                  ",
                "Safari\n                  ",
                "Sogou Explorer\n                  ",
                "Opera\n                  ",
                "QQ\n                  ",
                "Other\n                  "
            ],
            "title": {},
            "accessibility": {
                "description": "Line chart"
            }
        }
    ],
    "tooltip": {
        "shared": true
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "showInLegend": true,
            "events": {}
        },
        "column": {
            "maxPointWidth": 75
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "itemStyle": {
            "font": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
            "color": "#000"
        },
        "itemHoverStyle": {
            "color": "gray"
        }
    },
    "accessibility": {
        "description": null
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "2019",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                61.41,11.84,10.85,1,1,1.64,1.6,1,2.61
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "2020",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                50,40,20,15,14,12,6,4,3
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Confidence interval",
            "type": "errorbar",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                [55,65],
                [5,15],
                [7,25],
                [1,2],
                [1,2],
                [1,4],
                [1,3],
                [1,2],
                [2,4]
            ],
            "tooltip": {
                "pointFormat": "<strong>2019 error range</strong>: {point.low}-{point.high}<br/>"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Confidence interval",
            "type": "errorbar",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "data": [
                [45,55],
                [30,50],
                [15,30],
                [10,20],
                [10,20],
                [6,18],
                [4,8],
                [1,6],
                [1,6]
            ],
            "tooltip": {
                "pointFormat": "<strong>2020 error range</strong>: {point.low}-{point.high}<br/>"
            }
        }
    ],
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "colors": [
        "#b2182b",
        "#d6604d",
        "#f4a582",
        "#fddbc7",
        "#d1e5f0",
        "#92c5de",
        "#4393c3",
        "#2166ac"
    ]
}
```

And this is the result:
[image: Column chart with error bar]

As you can see from the hover state that the labels are displaying correctly but on the chart the error bars don't match each column. They are in reverse and misaligned. Also they are slightly different shape from each other.

I have used this HighCharts guide for reference, mine doesn't look much different from the example https://www.highcharts.com/demo/error-bar/grid-light

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is because the chart differently places the columns and error bars, especially it is visible with multiple columns.

After simplifying the demo, I was able to add one property called `pointPlacement` to the error series with the number to shift that series to a proper place.

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar.pointPlacement
**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L3xwoe92/